# Is there a way to build query string with key only in Angular?

Tags: angular, query-string

Recently while working on an Angular project, I've came up to situation where I need to pass *a key only* query parameter to a link. E.g. `http://localhost:4200/users/1?edit`. Yes, I want `?edit` only.

I've tried `[queryParams]="{edit: ''}"`. It gives me `http://localhost:4200/users/1?edit=`.

Is there any way to attain this? Or am I looking into impossible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have people forgotten how to use HTML? `<a href="/users/1?edit">how about them apples</a>`

Comment: Yes, tried it but it had some problems associated with it. Upon going with @HereticMonkey 's approach, the final URL if clicked on is turned out to be `http://localhost:4200/users/1?edit=` if done with `href`. The same URL turned `http://localhost:4200/users/1%3Fedit` if done with Angular's `routerLink`. SO, stuck here.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the integer after `users` is added dynamically, if that helps.

Comment: it's possible to have a router like `http:://localhost:4200/users/1/edit` but I'm don't know about use a `?edit`.

Comment: If writing it directly into the `href` attribute causes the browser to append the `=`, you're out of luck.

Comment: Even if you made this work, I kind of feel like you wouldn't be able to detect it on the page? Like wouldn't the value be `undefined` whether it was defined or not (if it had no value?). If you are able to change it, a better approach could be to make it `edit=true`, `edit=1` or `mode=edit`